# Redirect only desktop traffic to HTTPS with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to force redirect only desktop (non-mobile) traffic to HTTPS. I use Nginx and then reverse proxy to Apache for this particular domain. Here is my current configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://EXAMPLE_IP:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

With this Nginx code:

- Visiting http://www.example.com works.
- Visiting https://www.example.com works.

How do I add the logic to do User agent detection and do the right redirection?

I did discover this piece of code to do the detection of non-mobile traffic - https://gist.github.com/perusio/1326701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! Here is what worked for me:

```
### Testing if the client is a mobile or a desktop.
### The selection is based on the usual UA strings for desktop browsers.

## Testing a user agent using a method that reverts the logic of the
## UA detection. Inspired by notnotmobile.appspot.com.
map $http_user_agent $is_desktop {
    default 0;
    ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce|phone) 0; # exceptions to the rule
    ~*spider|crawl|slurp|bot 1; # bots
    ~*windows|linux|os\s+x\s*[\d\._]+|solaris|bsd 1; # OSes
}

server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://EXAMPLE_IP:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($is_desktop) {
        set $redirection A;
    }

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        set $redirection "${redirection}B";
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        set $redirection "${redirection}B";
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($redirection = AB) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://EXAMPLE_IP:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```